# ¿Como crear una prueba unitaria con C#?

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer pruebas unitarias, intente crear el proyecto a partir de la clase con la que queria practicar, pero obtengo un error:

```
The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Esta es la clase que se ha generado a partir de la clase deseo probar:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class AccountTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void WithdrawTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
}
```

También obtengo el error de que el espacio de nombres `VisualStudio` no existe. agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Estoy usando Visual Studio como entorno de desarrollo.

Acá esta la estructura de la solución, con el proyecto de pruebas que he generado, con la clase `Account` que es la que quiero probar incluida en el.

En este caso se renombro a `AccountTest` la clase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma he creado la prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He dejado el default para el resto de configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usualmente, cuando se hace UnitTesting se utiliza un proyecto aparte (**Proyecto de Pruebas Unitarias**). Pregunto: Creaste un proyecto de este tipo y escribiste esa clase, o agregaste la clase de prueba unitaria a un proyecto x que **no es de tipo "Proyecto de Pruebas Unitarias"**?

Comment: He creado un proyecto en la solución, lo he generado de forma automática. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2019 De la forma en que lo muestran ahí, ve al titulo "Generate unit test project and unit test stubs", he seguido esa guía

Comment: Primero que nada, te felicito por utilizar la documentación oficial. Segundo, nos puedes compartir un screenshot de la estructura de tu proyecto, en el Explorador de Soluciones?

Comment: Esta bien, ya la agrego

Comment: Si das click derecho en el proyecto `ConsoleApp2Test` y te vas a **propiedades**, puede que no sea del tipo UnitTest. Parece más una biblioteca de clases.

Comment: Si, no me había percatado de eso, pero me he fijado y resulta que no tengo instalado el componente para poder hacer pruebas unitarias, cuando instale el IDE trate de solo dejar lo necesario en aquel momento para que la descarga no tardara mucho y por eso tuve este problema, Al generar el proyecto no se genero un proyecto de pruebas por lo anterior que dije,  no me habia dado cuenta  (un poco torpe de mi parte). Gracias por la ayuda Arriel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la imagen que compartes, no parece ser que hayas añadido el tipo de proyecto correcto. El ícono de un proyecto de pruebas unitarias es distinto. El proyecto que ahí presentas parece ser una bibioteca de clases, y no un proyecto de pruebas unitarias. Te comparto una imagen de la creación de un nuevo proyecto en `Visual Studio 2019`, donde puede verse el ícono del proyecto (por tu imagen veo que tenemos versiones cercanas o similares):

[image: Proyecto de pruebas Unitarias]